# Arrange data frame column names in date order - R

Tags: r, tidyr

In my data frame I have 3 columns, out of which one column is date,

Example,

```
Region  variable value
TN      Jan-07   704
AU      Jan-07   3621
WB      Jan-07   776
KN      Jan-07   1015
TN.     Feb-07   90
KN.     Feb-07   87
```

I am pivoting the data frame from long to wide to keep each date (variable column) as one column header. Before pivot I can see that the date frame is ordered by date. However after my pivot, its ordering in alphabetical order like all Aprils first, August next, etc.. How do I order the column names by month ?

```
Out <- dcast(testdata,Region~variable,value.var = "value")
```

Output should be ,

```
Region Jan-07 Feb-07 Mar-07.....
TN. ............................
AU. ............................
WB. ............................
KN. ............................
```

But what I am getting is this,

```
Region Apr-07 Apr-08 Aug-07.....
TN. ............................
AU. ............................
WB. ............................
KN. ............................
```

Comment: Added my comment. Can you remove the duplicate thing ? @RonakShah

Comment: Please update your output based on the example data, instead of just `...............` . It makes the post unclear.

Comment: Question is about the column names, not the values. As I mentioned in the question, pivot is not returning the output columns in Jan 07, Feb 07,.. order, its returning the columns in this order Apr 07, Apr 08,.. Aug 07,Aug 08,...

Comment: Updated the issue in question, @RonakShah

Comment: does the code below work?

Comment: Yeah that works. But I prefer tidyr. Thanks anyways, I will go with this if this is not possible in tidyr.

Comment: A base R option would be `out[order(as.Date(paste0("01-", names(out[-1])), "%d-%b-%y"))]`

Comment: Thanks both of you. Both works. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
out <- reshape(testdata, idvar = "Region",
               timevar = "variable", direction = "wide")
out
```

Then just clean the `colnames`:

```
a = colnames(out)
b = sub('.*\\.', '', a)
colnames(out) = b
```

Answer (score 2):

You could turn the dates into a factor with the desired ordering before reshaping. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Change the factor levels to the appropriate year range for your data
testdata.wide = testdata %>% 
  mutate(variable=factor(variable, levels=apply(expand.grid(month.abb, substr(1990:2017,3,4)), 1, paste, collapse="-"))) %>%
  spread(variable, value)
```

> ```
>   Region Jan-07 Feb-07
> 1     AU   3621     NA
> 2     KN   1015     87
> 3     TN    704     90
> 4     WB    776     NA
> ```